# How to properly showing progressbar with ajax php and mysql

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to query a large data from the database and I wish to display a progress bar. The code below returns data info from the server but the progress bar just jumps to 100% while the Ajax is still querying data.

I guess the proper way is to fake the progress bar timer or possibly make a timely ajax call eg per seconds to update the progress bar. Can someone help me out with my issue? Thanks

Below is the working code so far

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function (e) {
 function pf(event) {
                                if (event.lengthComputable) {

                                var percentComplete = Math.round((event.loaded/event.total)*100);

                                $(".progressbar").width(percentComplete + '%');
                                $(".progressbar").html('<span>' + percentComplete +' %</span>')
                                $(".progressbar").html('<span> ' + percentComplete +'% Completed</span>')
                                }
                            };
    $("#sForm").on('submit',(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();



                   $('.progressbar').css('width', '0');
        $.ajax({

            url: "qdata.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:  new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,

                        xhr: function () {
                            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", pf, false);
                            return xhr;
                        },

            success: function(data)
            {

    if(data.trim() == "good"){
alert('completed now');
}
            },
            error: function() 
            {
            }           
       });
    }));
});


</script>
</head>
<body>


<div class="progressbar"></div>
<form id="sForm" action="qdata.php" method="post">
<div id="resultdata"></div>

<input type="submit" value="Submit now" />
</form>

</body> 
</html>
```

**qdata.php**

```
  // This is just sample db

    //dbconfig.php
    $result = $db->prepare('SELECT fullname FROM users');
    $result->execute(array());

    $count = $result->rowCount();

    while ($row = $result->fetch()) {

    $name=htmlentities($row['fullname'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");

    }

echo 'good';
```

Comment: There is no trivial way to make one request check on the “progress” of a completely independent one. PHP has a mechanism to check progress for file uploads, using the session - but that is not easily transferable to this situation. Plus, to be able to calculate any kind of percentage, you would not only need to know “where” you are currently, but also what the overall “amount” is – and that is not easily determinable here to begin with, until your script is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can show percentage of progress in `xhr` as

```
xhr: function () {
                        //upload Progress
                        var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                        if (xhr.upload) {
                            xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (event) {

                                var percent = 0;
                                var position = event.loaded || event.position;
                                var total = event.total;
                                if (event.lengthComputable) {
                                    percent = Math.ceil(position / total * 100);
                                }
                                //update progressbar
                                console.log('percent', percent);
                                $('.progressbar').css("width", percent + '%');
                            }, true);
                        }
                        return xhr;
                    },
```

Comment: I guess this requires that the server can determine the Content-Length of the response upfront? Otherwise, I don’t see how `event.total` could be determined. And if that is the case, it probably isn’t gonna help much - because how would the server do that, before all records have been processed.

Answer (score 0):

JS:

```
percent = 0;
var progressBar = $('#progress-bar');
$.ajax({
        url: "url.php",
        type: "post",
        data: "pg="+percent,
        success: function (return) {
            if ((return=="1")) {
                percent = parseInt(return);
                progressBar.width(percent + '%');
            }                   
        },
        error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        }
    });
```

HTML :

```
<div id="progress-bar" style="width: 0%"></div>
```

PHP :

```
$progress_value = (int) $_POST['pg'];

if ($progress_value==0) {
    sleep(1);//action
    $new_progress_bar = 10;
    exit($new_progress_bar);
}
if ($progress_value==10) {
    sleep(1);//action
    $new_progress_bar = 20;

    exit($new_progress_bar);
}
if ($progress_value==20) {
    sleep(1);//action
    $new_progress_bar = 30;

    exit($new_progress_bar);
}
```